# Navigate touch-tone menus via modem

Tags: voice, modem, at-command

I have a system that I need to programmatically interface with that requires a set of numbers to be dialed after the phone line is picked up, like a standard automated phone answering system. For instance, dial the number 123-456-7890, wait for the line to be answered, wait 15 seconds for the voice prompt, dial 1234#, hang up.

The question is, can I and how do I do that through a modem? I know how to dial a number through a modem, it's simply ATDT[phone number], but that will attempt to initiate a data connection which will not allow touch-tone number entry. Would a voice modem provide the necessary capability? If so, could anyone provide example commands to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Hayes Modem Reference](http://seriss.com/people/erco/unixtools/hayes.html) for a list of commands. To send DTMF tones on the line, you seem to have to use the `ATD` command. The comma (`,`) operator will pause the dialing for 2 seconds. This duration can also be customized by setting the `S7` register.

```
ATDT1234567890,,,,,,,1234#,;
ATH
```

This dials the number, waits 16 seconds, dials the code, waits another 2 seconds, and hangs up.

```
ATS7=15
ATDT1234567890,1234#;
ATH
```

This changes the comma delay, dials the number, waits 15 seconds, dials the code, and hangs up.

The `S7` register mentioned above, could also be `S8`. The manual and other sources doesn't want to agree.

Comment: Interesting. Looks like what I'm looking for. Guess I needed to read the documentation more closely. Thanks!